# Login-AzureRmAccount - Relying party: Microsoft Office 365 Identity Platform

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager

I was trying to login to my organization's Azure account using my org ID credentials but it is showing me below error after entering my org ID.

> An error occurred
>
> An error occurred. Contact your administrator for more information.
>
> Error details
>
> • Activity ID: 8226c490-a09f-4183-9ea8-a48eeecd26e8
>
> • Relying party: Microsoft Office 365 Identity Platform
>
> • Error time:
> Wed, 17 Aug 2016 12:35:28 GMT
>
> • Cookie: enabled
>
> • User agent string:
> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64;
> Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR
> 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.3; SLCC2; Media Center PC 6.0; Tablet PC 2.0)

This happens even when I try to check in my code from Visual Studio Code to TFS.

But, I can still login successfully if I Login using commands directly (without using login form):

```
$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $AzurePassword -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $AzureUserName, $securePassword
(Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $Cred -SubscriptionId $AzureSubscriptionID -ErrorAction Stop) | Out-Null
```

After doing some online search I found that, in order to resolve this issue we need to Enable forms-based authentication by using the steps in the following Microsoft TechNet topic: [Microsoft Technet Topic](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/3015526)

The above link explains how to do that on Windows Server 2012 but how to do that on Azure AD?

Can someone please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?
[Wiring up ASP.NET Web Application using Forms Authentication with SqlMembership Provider on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26985584/wiring-up-asp-net-web-application-using-forms-authentication-with-sqlmembership)

" In the Azure Portal, there is a setting that controls "Azure Websites Authentication / Authorization". Its found under Websites, then Configure, then scroll down a bit to "Azure Websites Authentication / Authorization". In my case there was an entry there: my website was tied into the "Directory" for my account and the "application" was set to my "tenant" (I think that's the Azure term).

To fix this, I simply removed the entry in the portal and I am able to login to my web application perfectly. Forms authentication wired up to Membership is working as I'd expect."

Comment: One of my team member has fixed the issue nut sadly he didn't reveal how he did that. He was somehow reluctant to share the solution. However, I believe your inputs would have helped. Not sure though.

Comment: @SavindraSingh: Eh, your colleague is a knob. If feel sad for you that you have to work with him.